# CosmicMind: How to transition between controllers within a container view using Motion

Tags: material-design, motion, cosmicmind

I try to implement the Motion feature with transition from one view controller to another when they are used in a container view.

This is what I want to achive:

1. Using a UIViewController that includes a container view,
2. Set the container view with a view controller that includes a table
3. When user selects the row, I want to transition to another view controller and at the same time animate the image in the table view to the image in the new viewcontroller.

So I have the following UIViewControllers:

1. Main UIViewController, with a containerView
   [image]
2. List UIViewController
3. Detail UIViewController

[image]

No I want to cycle, the list view controller with the detail, with a transition of the image.

Kind of like the [PhotoCollectionSample](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/PhotoCollection), but within a container view.

I have set the isMotionEnabled = true in the main view controller and the view controllers used in the container. I also have set the same motionIdentifier on the imageViews in both view controllers.

The issue I'm facing is how to transition between the controllers. Since I'm not using the UINavigationController or UITabBarController I don't think the animation is triggered.

At the moment I'm transition between controllers by using the implementation found here.

[Switching Child View Controllers in iOS with Auto Layout](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/13/switching-child-view-controllers-ios-auto-layout/)

But I think I have to do it in another way.

Comment: Have you tried presenting the view controller to trigger the animation? The API definition is `open func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil)`.

Comment: I updated the original question. Since I am using a container view I can't use the present method. That is my exact issue. I add the new view controllers as a child to current view controller and the adds it's view to the container.

Comment: The latest version of Motion will include the feature you are looking for. I am aiming to have it released within a week. I am completing an entire rewrite of the framework.

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to that. Please update this question with an example when its released. Keep up the great work with the framework. I love it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
/**
 A helper transition function.
 - Parameter from: A UIViewController.
 - Parameter to: A UIViewController. 
 - Parameter in view: A UIView.
 - Parameter completion: An optional completion handler.
 */
 func transition(from: UIViewController, to: UIViewController, in view: UIView, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

and call it like this:

```
Motion.shared.transition(from: vc1, to: vc2, in: container)
```

That should work :)